# Reconcile dataset *column types* (formats) using a dictionary/list in R/dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, types, tidyverse, purrr

Following on the [renaming request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67453183/how-to-effectively-append-datasets-using-a-dictionary-with-r-dplyr-how-to-c) #67453183 I want to do the same for *formats* using the dictionary, because it won't bring together columns of distinct types.

> I have a series of data sets and a dictionary to bring these together. But I'm struggling to figure out how to automate this. > Suppose this data and dictionary (actual one is much longer, thus I want to automate):

```
mtcarsA <- mtcars[1:2,1:3] %>% rename(mpgA = mpg, cyl_A = cyl) %>% as_tibble()
mtcarsB <- mtcars[3:4,1:3] %>% rename(mpg_B = mpg, B_cyl = cyl) %>% as_tibble()
mtcarsB$B_cyl <- as.factor(mtcarsB$B_cyl)

dic <- tibble(true_name  = c("mpg_true", "cyl_true"), 
              nameA = c("mpgA", "cyl_A"), 
              nameB = c("mpg_B", "B_cyl"),
              true_format = c("factor", "numeric")
)
```

> I want these datasets (from years A and B) appended to one another, and then to have the names changed or coalesced to the 'true_name' values....  I want to automate 'coalesce all columns with duplicate names'.

And to bring these together, the types need to be the same too. I'm giving the entire problem here because perhaps someone also has a better solution for 'using a data dictionary'.

@ronakShah in the previous query proposed

```
pmap(dic, ~setNames(..1, paste0(c(..2, ..3), collapse = '|'))) %>%
  flatten_chr() -> val

mtcars_all <- list(mtcarsA,mtcarsB) %>%
  map_df(function(x) x %>% rename_with(~str_replace_all(.x, val)))
```

Which works great in the previous example but *not* if the formats vary.  Here it throws error:

`Error: Can't combine` ..1$cyl_true`<double> and`..2$cyl_true `<factor<51fac>>.`

[This response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56773548/11234387) to #56773354 offers a related solution if one has a *complete* list of types, but not for a type list by column name, as I have.

**Desired output:**

```
mtcars_all
# A tibble: 4 x 3

mpg_true cyl_true  disp
  <factor> <numeric> <dbl>
1    21     6   160
2    21     6   160
3    22.8   4   108
4    21.4   6   258
```

Comment: An example of desired output would help.

Comment: Done, thanks. (And not the formats/types)

Note that I can obviously do this by brute force but I want to use the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something simpler:

```r
library(magrittr) # %<>% is cool
library(dplyr)

# The renaming is easy:

renameA <- dic$nameA
renameB <- dic$nameB
names(renameA) <- dic$true_name
names(renameB) <- dic$true_name

mtcarsA %<>% rename(all_of(renameA))
mtcarsB %<>% rename(all_of(renameB))

# Formatting is a little harder:

formats <- dic$true_format
names(formats) <- dic$true_name

lapply(names(formats), function (x) {
  # there's no nice programmatic way to do this, I think
  coercer <- switch(formats[[x]], 
                      factor = as.factor,
                      numeric = as.numeric,
                      warning("Unrecognized format") 
                    )
  mtcarsA[[x]] <<- coercer(mtcarsA[[x]])
  mtcarsB[[x]] <<- coercer(mtcarsB[[x]])
})

mtcars_all <- bind_rows(mtcarsA, mtcarsB)
```

In the background you should be aware of how base R treated concatenating factors before 4.1.0, and how this'll change. Here it probably doesn't matter because `bind_rows` will use the `vctrs` package.

Comment: Nice, but I realised that this doesn't work if my data frames have different numbers of columns; edited MWE to adapt to this. 

Also, any way to 'automate' the following bit for a list `c("A", "B")`?

`renameA <- dic$nameA`

`renameB <- dic$nameB`

`names(renameA) <- dic$true_name`

`names(renameB) <- dic$true_name`

```

etc

Comment: 1. Add an `if` statement in the lapply function. 2. Yes. 3. You've moved the goalposts, and now my answer doesn't work because you've changed the question, which either requires me to do more free work for you, or confuses other readers.

Comment: Good point. I wasn't sure if it would be better to 'move the goalpost' or make an entirely new post linked to the first one at the cost of redundancy.  Will fix this. I will return this back to the original post and add an additional post if it makes sense.

Comment: Tried to edit my last grumpy comment but it was too late... anyway yup fine....

Comment: OK, I 'rolled it back' to the earlier one to avoid confusion and goalpost-moving.

For those wondering, I had changed it adding a third dataset and a new column in that data set only to better reflect my actual problem. I believe that's what @dash2's `if` statement in the comment above addresses.

Comment: This switch statement is great, but the `warning` should be a `stop`. Otherwise the `warning` will get given to the console and assign `NULL` to the variable `coercer` and then it will crash later on in a confusing way.

Comment: Also, the "if" statement @dash2 mentions works nicely as follows:

```if(!is.null(mtcarsA[[x]])){}``` 

This allows it to process the datasets even if they don't each contain all of the columns in the dictionary.

Comment: And also instead of `bindrows`... 
using `plyr::rbind.fill` allows you to bind rows with different numbers of columns

Answer (score 1):

I took another approach than Ronak's to read the dictionary. It is more verbose but I find it a bit more readable. A benchmark would be interesting to see which one is faster ;-)

Unfortunately, it seems that you cannot blindly cast a variable to a factor so I switched to character instead. In practice, it should behave exactly like a factor and you can call `as_factor()` on the end object if this is very important to you. Another possibility would be to store a casting function name (such as `as_factor()`) in the dictionary, retrieve it using `get()` and use it instead of `as()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcarsA <- mtcars[1:2,1:3] %>% rename(mpgA = mpg, cyl_A = cyl) %>% as_tibble()
mtcarsB <- mtcars[3:4,1:3] %>% rename(mpg_B = mpg, B_cyl = cyl) %>% as_tibble()
mtcarsB$B_cyl <- as.factor(mtcarsB$B_cyl)

dic <- tibble(true_name  = c("mpg_true", "cyl_true"), 
              nameA = c("mpgA", "cyl_A"), 
              nameB = c("mpg_B", "B_cyl"),
              true_format = c("numeric", "character") #instead of factor
)

dic2 = dic %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(true_name, true_format), names_to=NULL)

read_dic = function(key, dict=dic2){
  x = dict[dict$value==key,][["true_name"]]
  if(length(x)!=1) x=key
  x
}

rename_from_dic = function(df, dict=dic2){
  rename_with(df, ~{
    map_chr(.x, ~read_dic(.x, dict))
  })
}

cast_from_dic = function(df, dict=dic){
  mutate(df, across(everything(), ~{
    cl=dict[dict$true_name==cur_column(),][["true_format"]]
    if(length(cl)!=1) cl=class(.x)
    as(.x, cl, strict=FALSE)
  }))
}

list(mtcarsA,mtcarsB) %>% 
  map(rename_from_dic) %>% 
  map_df(cast_from_dic)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   mpg_true cyl_true  disp
#>      <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1     21   6          160
#> 2     21   6          160
#> 3     22.8 4          108
#> 4     21.4 6          258
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>